# How to extract class IL code from loaded assembly and save to disk?

Tags: serialization, reflection, mono, reflection.emit, il

How would I go about extracting the IL code for classes that are generated at runtime by reflection so I can save it to disk? If at all possible. I don't have control of the piece of code that generates these classes.

Eventually, I would like to load this IL code from disk into another assembly.

I know I could serialise/deserialise classes but I wish to use purely IL code. I'm not fussed with the security implications.

Running Mono 2.10.1

Comment: This is just wrong, code != data.

Comment: As Hans commented, IL will not contain username & password. Even serialization is bad idea for username & password. Probably by explaining your actual problem you can help community come up with better solution & answer.

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar It was purely an example. I said I wanted to "populate its properties with runtime calculated values". I didn't think IL code contained data, by this I meant I wanted to create an instance of the class I just injected and alter is values using reflection. Overall, I want to be able to extract the IL code of any object that may contain any amount of properties, fields and methods.

Comment: Can you mention difference between storing/loading DLL and storing/loading IL?

Comment: @Akash I have edited my question to state that the classes in which I am trying to extract IL code for may or may not be created by reflection. Hence no IL code for classes created via reflection will be stored in the DLL.

Comment: @Steven, you said serialization was one option in your original question, that's why it was hard to understand whether u wanted data or code.

Comment: @Steven your edit does not answer my question, also IL will not work without all referenced IL merged in your dll.

Comment: For some reason I'm still unable to understand this question, can someone edit it to make some sense?

Comment: @Akash @Senjeevakimar @Hans I have edited the question again to try and simplify it. Please accept my apologies for not making myself clear. However, as Akash pointed out, it seems what I want to do is not possible. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or better yet, use Mono.Cecil.

It will allow you to get at the individual instructions, even manipulating them and disassembling them (with the [mono decompiler addition](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2008/12/15/cecil-decompiler)).

Note that the decompiler is a work in progress (last time I checked it did not fully support lambda expressions and Visual Basic exception blocks), but you can have pretty decompiled output in C# pretty easily as far as you don't hit these boundary conditions. Also, work has progressed since.

Mono Cecil in general let's you write the IL to a new assembly, as well, which you can then subsequently load into your appdomain if you like to play with bleeding edge.

**Update** I came round to trying this. Unfortunately I think I found what problem you run into. It turns out there is seems to be no way to get at the IL bytes for a generated type *unless* the assembly happened to get written out somewhere you can load it from.

I assumed you could just get the bits via reflection (since the classes support the required methods), however the related methods just raise an exception `The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic module.` on invocation. You can try this with the code below, but **in short I suppose it means that it ain't gonna happen** unless you want to [f*ck with `Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx). You'd have to binary dump the instructions and manually disassemble them as IL opcodes. There be dragons.

Code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Reflection;

namespace REFLECT
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Type EmitType()
        {
            var dyn = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Emitted"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
            var mod = dyn.DefineDynamicModule("Emitted", "Emitted.dll");
            var typ = mod.DefineType("EmittedNS.EmittedType", System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Public);
            var mth = typ.DefineMethod("SuperSecretEncryption", System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Public | System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(String), new [] {typeof(String)});

            var il = mth.GetILGenerator();
            il.EmitWriteLine("Emit was here");
            il.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_0);    
            il.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);
            var result = typ.CreateType();
            dyn.Save("Emitted.dll");
            return result;
        }

        private static Type TestEmit()
        {
            var result = EmitType();
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(result);
            var encrypted = instance.GetType().GetMethod("SuperSecretEncryption").Invoke(null, new [] { "Hello world" });
            Console.WriteLine(encrypted); // This works happily, print "Emit was here" first

            return result;
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Type emitted = TestEmit();

              // CRASH HERE: even if the assembly was actually for SaveAndRun _and_ it 
              // has actually been saved, there seems to be no way to get at the image
              // directly:
            var ass = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly(emitted.Assembly.GetFiles(false)[0]);

              // the rest was intended as mockup on how to isolate the interesting bits
              // but I didn't get much chance to test that :)
            var types = ass.Modules.Cast<ModuleDefinition>().SelectMany(m => m.Types.Cast<TypeDefinition>()).ToList();
            var typ = types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == emitted.Name);

            var operands = typ.Methods.Cast<MethodDefinition>()
                .SelectMany(m => m.Body.Instructions.Cast<Instruction>())
                .Select(i => i.Operand);

            var requiredTypes = operands.OfType<TypeReference>()
                .Concat(operands.OfType<MethodReference>().Select(mr => mr.DeclaringType))
                .Select(tr => tr.Resolve()).OfType<TypeDefinition>()
                .Distinct();
            var requiredAssemblies = requiredTypes
                .Select(tr => tr.Module).OfType<ModuleDefinition>()
                .Select(md => md.Assembly.Name as AssemblyNameReference);

            foreach (var t in types.Except(requiredTypes))
                ass.MainModule.Types.Remove(t);

            foreach (var unused in ass.MainModule
                     .AssemblyReferences.Cast<AssemblyNameReference>().ToList()
                     .Except(requiredAssemblies))
                ass.MainModule.AssemblyReferences.Remove(unused);

            AssemblyFactory.SaveAssembly(ass, "/tmp/TestCecil.dll");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately because Mono.Cecil lacks official documentation I can't find an example that would allow me to save the IL code that represents a specific class to a file. Does it allow you to inject IL code into the current appdomain?

Comment: Mono's repo contain [cecil-roundtrip.cs](https://github.com/mono/cecil/blob/master/tools/cecil-roundtrip.cs) which I suppose should be pretty comprehensive to start things. I'll see whether I can knock up a little sample

Comment: Updated with bad news. Sorry :) One more suggestion, but I'm not sure I would go there

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the IL for your `User` class, you already have it. It's in the dll that you compiled it to.

From your other assembly, you can [load the dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx) with the `User` class dynamically and [use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dex1ss7c.aspx) through reflection.

**UPDATE**:

If what you have is a dynamic class created with `Reflection.Emit`, you have an `AssemblyBuilder` that you can use to [save it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.save.aspx) to disk.

If your dynamic type was instead created with `Mono.Cecil`, you have an `AssemblyDefinition` that you can save to disk with `myAssemblyDefinition.Write("MyAssembly.dll")` (in Mono.Cecil 0.9).